# Rocket launch ground track mapper

Tags: ground-track, launch-trajectories

I'm looking for a tool for plotting the ground tracks of rocket launches at particular inclinations from particular launch sites, but haven't found anything so far; can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This is hard because rocket launch trajectories are not defined by only location, direction and inclination.

Comment: Have you seen flightclub.io?